# Using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo to get performance metrics

Tags: c#, .net, sql, performancecounter, smo

Was wondering how I can programmatically get performance metrics for a given sql server instance or database by using **SMO** (sql management objects).
Basically similar to what the Activity Monitor in Sql Management Studio displays.

*So for example if I want to know things like the CPU usage, I/O writes, etc, which SMO object will give me that?*

I've tried using the following but I don't think I'm on the right track.

```
Server srv = new Server(conn);

DataRow[] datarows = srv.EnumPerformanceCounters().Select();
```

Comment: Correct.  That's what I need.  The values for the counters.  But I can't find which classes in the SMO namespace(s) do that.

Comment: The EnumPerformanceCounters() method seems to returns information that only indicates the ObjectName, CounterName and InstanceName of a given counter.